# Laravel search in two tables other than using morph

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables, "sales," "person," and "company," where the table "sales" has a morph relationship with the other two. I need to look up the "person" and "company" tables together. If I had another table "customer" with the related morph between "person" and "company," I would vary it this way.

```
$customers = (new Customer)->whereHasMorph('customer',
    [
        Person::class,
        Company::class,
    ], function (Builder $query, $type) use ($request) {
        if ($request->get('search') !== null) {
            if ($type === Person::class) {
                $query->whereHas('customer',
                    function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
                        $query->whereFulltext(
                            ['document', 'name'],
                            $request->get('search').':*',
                            ['language' => 'portuguese']
                        );
                    });
                if ($type === Company::class) {
                    $query->whereHas('customer',
                        function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
                            $query->whereFulltext(
                                ['document', 'company'],
                                $request->get('search').':*',
                                ['language' => 'portuguese']
                            );
                        });
                }
            }
        }
        return response()->json($customers->paginate(10));
    }
);
```

The "person" and "company" tables have different fields. I need to solve this problem of the "customer" table.

Comment: You have it almost right. 
basically if i am not mistaken you are looking for person or company or person and company I would do a ->where(function($query) { apply whereHas Logic})
orWhere(function($query) { apply whereHas Logic})

Comment: I still don't understand how to do it I'm new to laravel

Answer (score 0):

```php
$customer = Sales::query()
                      ->with('customer')
                      ->whereHasMorph('customer', function($query) {
                           $query->where('morphable_type', Person::class)
                           ->orWhere(''morphable', Company::class);
                       })->get()
```

then you get the Customer from every sales or
$customer = Customer::whereHasMorphable('sales')->get()

the thing is you are trying now to a customer relation on a customer model, so basically you are looking for customers of the customer.

If you are using a customer table...

maybe something like this? ->whereIn('morphable_type', [Person::class, Customer::class])

Comment: so the problem is that I can't use the "sales" model in the search

I'm using the search to find a record that will be inserted in the sales model, the record can be person or company

Comment: So you have a table with customers and they have morphable entities Person and company.

so 
id | morpahble_type|morphable_id|some column etc... ???